# Count the number of specific character inside string with text delimiter

Tags: php

I have string:

```
$output = "Program: First 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Program: Second 0 0 0 0 0 Program: Third 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0";
```

I need this output:

```
$output = "Program: First 7 Program: Second 5 Program: Third 8";
```

I know i can count all "0" occurences with "substr_count", but how i can count specific group of zeros before text "Program"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would exactly output what you need. Its not that beautiful, u might find a better solution with google, but that just came into my mind:

```
<?php

$output = "Program: First 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Program: Second 0 0 0 0 0 Program: Third 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0";

$output = explode("Program:", $output);
array_splice($output, 0,1 );
$endString = '';
foreach($output as $elem) {
    $count = substr_count($elem, "0");
    $elemWithoutZero = str_replace('0', '', $elem);
    $endString = $endString . 'Program: ' . $elemWithoutZero . $count . ' ';
}
var_dump($endString);


?>
```

Output:

```
string(74) "Program: First 7 Program: Second 5 Program: Third 8"
```

Anyways if you get that kind of data, you might find a better solution at the place where you create that data.

Comment: @user2337706 I hope you'r understanding what happens there, so you can write it yourself next time :)

Comment: Yes i will analyze it. I don't like to disturb people, but sometime i can spend hours to write so simple code)

Answer (score 2):

Can do this:

```
$output = "Program: First 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Program: Second 0 0 0 0 0 Program: Third 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0";
$pieces = explode('Program',$output);
foreach($pieces as $piece){
   echo substr_count($piece, '0').PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
0
7
5
8
```

Other way:

```
$programs = Array('First','Second','Third');
$output = "Program: First 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Program: Second 0 0 0 0 0 Program: Third 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0";
$pieces = explode(' Program:',$output);
$looutput = '';
$i = 0;
foreach($pieces as $piece){
   $loutput .= 'Program: '.$programs[$i].' '.substr_count($piece, '0').' ';
   $i++;
}
echo $loutput;
```

Output:

```
Program: First 7 Program: Second 5 Program: Third 8
```

Comment: not bad, but it doesn't saves Program: First, Second for current output.

Comment: Your question was "how can i count specific group of zeros before text Program" then I thought knowing the amount of zeros, do know the replacement.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me that the response of @Xatenev is better.

Answer (score 1):

`substr_count` can be provided a maximum length to count till. Simply use `strpos` to find the index of "Second" and count the 0's to that index. You can also provide 'substr_count' with an offset, so start at the offset for the next range of zeroes.

[substr_count Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)